# Chrome Heap Snapshot -- no colors for detached nodes

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) under "Discover detached DOM tree memory leaks with Heap Snapshots".

When I search for detached nodes, I see a bunch of "Detached" elements. But when I expand them, none of the contained elements are red or yellow, as described in the tutorial.

Has this behavior changed? I'm using 70.0.3538.77 for Mac.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following [this proposal](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=851195), the color coding was replaced by icons with tooltips:

**JS object that is reachable from window**
Was: yellow highlight
Now: icon of a small window

**DOM object that is detached from the tree**
Was: red highlight
Now: icon with a pair of scissors

Comment: For others who may stumble onto this answer, note that Chrome 79 (and perhaps other versions) has a bug where these icons render instead as empty squares: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=989643