# Chrome Dev Tools: memory heap snapshot shows special icon instead of unicode character (previously red/yellow highlight)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome dev tools memory tab to isolate a memory leak in an application. When I look at the snapshot of the JS heap, there should be a way for me to distinguish which pieces of data DO NOT have direct references as indicated by the docs – these were highlighted in red (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/).

This issue explains why there are no colors, and instead there should be icons ([Chrome Heap Snapshot -- no colors for detached nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109488/chrome-heap-snapshot-no-colors-for-detached-nodes)).

Now, the issue I am having is that the icons that should be there are rendering as just a box .

I have tried the solutions listed here: https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0QyAwmbsj7iU/?hl=en&gpf=%23!topic%2Fchrome%2FQyAwmbsj7iU

Nothing seemed to work for me. I DO have adobe create cloud, but nothing was running at the time, and I did not have the option to manage fonts as described in the most popular solution.

I should get an icon describing the data's heigher archy in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue but I just run into this myself. The way I fixed it for me was to install Unicode Fonts for Ancient Scripts (ttf-ancient-fonts package in ubuntu) and then restart Chrome. After that I was able to see the icons properly.